# how can I create soap proxy from a rest backend in wso2 api manager 4.1.0

Tags: rest, soap, wso2, wso2-api-manager

My reference/endpoint service is rest and I want a soap proxy and my soap proxy must also have a WSDL file.

How can I do it in WSO2 API manager 4.1.0 ?